# Issue with executing Powershell commands in .ps1 from windows command prompt using powershell.exe

Tags: powershell, command-line

I am facing issue when executing powershell commands written in .ps1 file in windows command tool (cmd.exe).
Below is how i am trying to execute

1. Open command prompt
2. Execute powershell -> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe -file C:\Users\Usha\Desktop\foldername\powershellfile.ps1

The powershell file (powershellfile.ps1) has below lines of code

```
$jsonStr = Get-Content -Raw -Path C:\Users\Usha\Desktop\foldername\filename.json | ConvertFrom-JSON
New-Item -Path 'D:\ps' -Name 'testfile.txt' -ItemType 'file'
```

But it gives below error
Get-Content : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Raw'

If i remove the 1st like line, it gives error to 2nd line when creating file as below
Out-file : Cannot find drive. A drive with name ''c' doesnot exist.

Here i am giving location as c:\users\desktop\foldername

The script works fine when running in windows powershell. But this only exists when running using powershell.exe as above.

I am unable to understand how to fix as everywhere in internet it is told to execute by invoking powerhsell.exe

Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance,
Usha.
Please help me

Comment: Update your question to show the code as it actually is, what exactly do you have in place of: <<Path of json file\filename.json>>  Also exactly what are you typing for step 2? What's with the -> <> ?

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Also looks like the commands in the script are executing when triggering powershhell script using powershell.exe from command prompt in my local system. But doesnt work when working in my client system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the issue by setting the execution policy to `unrestricted`, as below

```
C:\Windows\System32\PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -command script.ps1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question title says commands but your poorly-formatted code suggests you're passing a file.

Which is it?

How to call a file:

```
powershell.exe -file "C:\path\to\file.ps1"
# or
powershell.exe -file "C:\path\to\file.ps1" -param value
```

How to run a command:

```
powershell.exe -command "get-date; whoami"
# or
powershell.exe -c "& {get-date; 'a string'; "another complicated string$(Get-random @('!','?','.'))" }"
```

OR....

RTFM `powershell.exe /?`

---

Friendly Tip: 
You would better comprehend the right method if you create a simple script with just `$env:username`, figure out how to execute that, then try your script.

Comment: i am able to call the powershell file without issues with powershell.exe -file file.ps1, but the commands inside the file are erroring if i execute ps1 file by calling though powershell.exe. If i directly open windows powerhsell and execute, then the script is executing without failing at any command.

Comment: Your script (updated recently in OP) shows you storing data into a variable and creating a new file, but you don't do anything with the data. Regardless, the errors you're getting almost seems like you're running an older version of powershell or there is some corruption on your OS, or maybe a security policy. Have you tried running this on a different computer? Make a script with this content and run it: `$psversiontable; $host; gcm gc|fl *; help gc -param raw` and post the output to a pastebin.

Comment: PS version shown is  5.1.19041.1682. So i doubt it shouldnt be a problem with version. Also the script runs fine when executing directly opening windowspowershell. Only problem if when invoking powershell.exe from command prompt.

Comment: Did you try running on a different computer? What about the other commands I said to run?

Comment: I want to see a screenshot of the command window including title bar and the command you ran and the result; take multiple if needed. You need to run my commands from the previous comment as instructed in my original answer. Don't assume it should behave the same way.

Comment: When running the command given '$psversiontable; $host; gcm gc|fl *; help gc -param raw'  as "C:\Users\X1242028>C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe $psversiontable; $host; gcm gc|fl *; help gc -param raw" but i received error as "'fl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
But when i execute same command in windows powershell it executed successfully giving a long message.

Comment: specifying version fixed this error in my local machine. But issue still exists in server. What could be the reason?

Comment: Your execution is sloppy. You need to first learn the finer points of executing powershell code from the command prompt, ie: don't just throw code at the executable and expect it to work. Learn the syntax. I tried to show you above but you didn't listen and aren't following my instructions. I'm glad to help further but I won't repeat myself and you're not going to upvote my answer. Maybe someone else's tutorial will be of better help: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-run-powershell-commands-from-the-command-prompt

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am learning powershell and trying my best to implement. The powerhsell code i have written executes fine now in my local but not in server which i am not able to crack it because the fix i applied works in my local and not in server :(

Comment: I am able to finally fix the issue on server by setting execution policy to 'unrestricted' which worked.

Answer (score 0):

I can recreate this error in powershell 2.0. You will need 3 or later to use the raw parameter to get-content. Check your version using the variable $psversiontable

Or you can consider why you are using the raw parameter and if you really need it.

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check, good sir!

Comment: Yes, but the powershell version i have is 5.1.19041.1682. Also, the script executes successfully those commands in windows powershell. Issues comes only when i execute as below in command line by triggering powershell.exe 
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe -file C:\Users\Usha\Desktop\foldername\powershellfile.ps1
So i am unable to understand if there is any older version of powershell being called or any other issue. 
Even when i execute $psversiontable it shows version as 5.1.19041.1682
if i remove -Raw then it is giving error at ConvertFrom-Json.

Comment: specifying version fixed this error in my local machine. But issue still exists in server. What could be the reason?